# Microsoft Print to PDFのドライバーの作り方

Tags: windows

#### 質問

Microsoft Print to PDFで次のことをやりたいです。

・予め設定ファイル（conf.txt）に「文字列」と「番号」を書いておく。
・印刷時にconf.txtを読んでPDFを「文字列+番号.pdf」というファイル名（パス）で保存する。また、conf.txtの番号に+1する。
・もしconf.txtが無かったら、通常通りユーザがファイル名と場所を指定する。

たぶん「プリンタドライバーの開発」になると思いますが、知識がない上に調べても分かりやすい情報源がなく、よく分かりません。

#### やったこと

・Visual Studioをインストール
・Windows 10 SDKをインストール
・Windows Driver Kitをインストール

#### できないこと

Microsoft Print to PDFのドライバ作成。

#### 追記

プログラムはブラウザの印刷機能から呼び出されるようにしたいです。プリンタを選択する時に現状では「Microsoft Print to PDF」が選択肢にありますが、新しく「My Print to PDF」のようなものを作ることになると思います。この作り方が分かりません。

Comment: この記事とかが参考になるのでは？ [Microsoft Print to PDF で C/C++ コードから出力ファイル名を指定する方法](https://perce-neige.hateblo.jp/entry/2018/09/14/180047)

Comment: [XY問題](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2701/26370)のような気がします。本当にやりたい大きな範囲の課題があって、その中の1ステップについての質問では？ 質問内容のことをやりたい本当の要求は何かを問い直した方が良さそうです。

Answer (score -1, accepted):

ちなみに、Windows Driver KitのドライバーサンプルにはMicrosoft Print to PDFのソースコードは無いようです。

サンプルに何が入っているかの説明ページはこれ。
XPSは複数ありますがPDFは含まれていません。
[印刷ドライバーのサンプル](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows-hardware/drivers/samples/print-driver-samples)

サンプルの中でマイクロソフトの印刷ドライバと明記されているのはこちらの2つ。
[Microsoft のプリンター ドライバーをカスタマイズします。](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows-hardware/drivers/print/customizing-microsoft-s-printer-drivers)

- Microsoft ユニバーサル プリンター ドライバー (Unidrv)
- Microsoft PostScript プリンター ドライバー (Pscript)

なので、**Microsoft Print to PDF** をカスタマイズすることは出来ないでしょう。
取り敢えず代替手段として以下のような例が考えられます。

- あくまでMicrosoft Print to PDFのカスタマイズにこだわる
  あまり現実的じゃないですが、Microsoftと交渉して改造用にMicrosoft Print to PDFのソースコードを購入する
- Microsoft Print to PDFを使えれば良い
  私のコメントや@池田茂樹さん回答の手段等によりプリンタドライバは変更せずに、アプリケーションやユーティリティで出力ファイル名を自動で指定出来るようにする
- PDF形式に出力出来れば良い
  オープンソースのPDFプリンタドライバが複数あるので、その中から好みのものを選んで目的の機能を追加する
- ファイルに出力出来れば良い
  上記Microsoft PostScript プリンター ドライバーか、サンプルや解説の多数あるXPS形式のファイル出力を改造して目的の機能を追加する

Answer (score -1):

これが参考になりませんか？
プログラミング言語はC#です。

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31896952/how-to-programmatically-print-to-pdf-file-without-prompting-for-filename-in-c-sh